# Replace the inside part only of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Suppose I have the following list:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: {
        Apple,
        Orange,
        Appricot
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li v-for=item in items>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to do the following:

If I click on one of the list items, I want its inner side to be replaced with some info (let's say, some text, like 'Tomato'). How can I do that without replacing the insides of all of the list items?

Comment: Set up a click event handler for the `<li>` elements that contains: `this.textContent = "your data here"`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus in this case all of the elements will be replaced with the new data

Comment: No they won't. Not if you set up a click event for the `li` elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but what if I don't want to hardcode the text and I have an html element, that should be shown istead of the clicked element, for example: <div> Tomato </div> How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below codes will work for you

template:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-on:click="changeText(index)">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

methods:

```
changeText: function (index) {
     this.items[index]="Tomato";
}
```

Comment: It must be  `@click` not `ng-click`

Comment: @Bikimallik but what if I don't want to hardcode the text and I have an html element, that should be shown istead of the clicked element, for example:

<div> Tomato </div>

How can I do that?

Comment: you have to add dynamic id to each of <li> and use the innerHTML() to